# EditText appears in front of listview items

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="-1sp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/commentFooter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/post_message" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

where the `include` called `post_message` is a `RelativeLayout` with an `EditText` and a `Button`.

The problem is the `include` appears above the list items at the bottom of the list. How can I make it appear below the list?

Comment: Use a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation.

Comment: @Singularity Thanks. If I use LL, how can I later make a loading spinner appears in the middle of the layout? That's why I started out with a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Easy, Place that too in LinearLayout with layout gravity = center and visibilty = gone. Now to show spinner : set other views visibilty = gone, and spinner's visibilty = visible.

Comment: Understood, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Pierre Rymiortz have u check my solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have try this i checked it works for you.

& show like As shown in image

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="-1sp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/commentFooter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/commentFooter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"    
    layout="@layout/article_view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `android:layout_below=""` ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, tried it. Position works but also stretches the include to fill the space up to the bottom of the list in case there is only a few list items. Any solution for this?

Comment: Change the width to wrap_content, I think. Are you saying you want it to stretch or you don't?

Comment: Not stretch, vertically. Dixit's answer solved it. Thanks for your help, I've +1 your answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Ah I see what you meant.